# How can add new fields inside crm.lead model via custom module inheriting crm.lead model in odoo 11?

Tags: crm, odoo

[image]According to requirements, need to customize Contact Us form which inserts into CRM.lead model (CRM module - Odoo 11)
I need to add additional fields in this model.
Issue! Already added new fields in this model but now showing on form view.

```
<record id="crm_case_form_view_leads_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.form.lead.inherited</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <notebook position="inside">
            <page string="Extra fields">
                <group>
                    <field name="field_x"/>
                    <field name="field_y"/>
                    <field name="field_z"/>
                </group>
            </page>
        </notebook>            
    </field>


class Lead(models.Model):
_inherit = 'crm.lead'
field_x = fields.Char(string='Field X)
field_y = fields.Text(string='Field Y')
field_z = fields.Char(string='Field Z')
```

Problem is not showing fields values on form view.

Check this link which appears as issue :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZoqU2REHlpwJm_oQ7mXJmNJSqF8v22KA/view

Comment: So... What seems to be your issue apart from code indentation and xml record close tag?

Comment: Issue is not showing values submitted from Contact form on form view

Comment: Contact form of the Website? Did you customize the contact form to comply with form builder contract for crm.lead?

Comment: Look at snap shop as i mentioned now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<record id="crm_case_form_view_leads_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">crm.lead.form.lead.inherited</field>
<field name="model">crm.lead</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor" /> 
<field name="arch" type="xml">

    <xpath expr="//page[@name='lead']" position="after">
        <page string="Extra fields">
            <group>
                <field name="field_x"/>
                <field name="field_y"/>
                <field name="field_z"/>
            </group>
        </page>
    </xpath>
</field>
```

Comment: This link shows issue what i am facing :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZoqU2REHlpwJm_oQ7mXJmNJSqF8v22KA/view